# bundling large Vue application using webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Currently, I am working on a large Vue JS project which has many modules. The structure we are looking at is as follows:

```
app/
    moduleA/
        components/
        vuex/
        index.js
        routes.js

   moduleB/
        components/
        vuex/
        index.js
        routes.js

    shared/
        components/
        vuex/
        index.js
        routes.js

   vuex.js
   Main.vue
   router/
   vuex/
   components/ -> shared
   main.js
```

Each module here is like a small project in itself and can have different dependencies. I am not sure how to set up the bundling for this project.

The one option which I can think of is having webpack config setup for each module which would create separate distribution files and somehow collate these together to create a build.

Any help in bundling strategy of this project would be great help?

Comment: To get the answer you need to provide more constraint. (bundle size, is async module allow...)
You can create one unique bundle if the size is not that big.